# upload file to google cloude storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I try to make upload to google cloud storage use nodejs , and I get some error

This is the code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: "jerk-70c86hks6f0c.json",
  projectId: "jerk",
});
const bucketName = "mystorage";

module.exports = {
  upload: (myfile, videoid) => {
    return (await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(myfile.path, {
      gzip: true,
      destination: "kids/video/"+{videoid}+".mp4",
      metadata: {
        cacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000",
      },
    }));
  },
};
```

This is the result

```
return (await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(myfile.path, {
                  ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Can you guys explain to me why error ? , thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you are getting is because it didn't expect storage to be there. The error is due to `await`. You only use `await` in an `async` function.

Either make your function async or remove that await.

Here is an example:

```
async function myAsyncFunction() {
  let result = await lengthyFunction();    
  console.log(result);
}

myAsyncFunction();
```

Also [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) you can see an example in the documentation where the upload is not being called in an async way since it is not inside of an async function